# Create an array inside array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an imaging web service where I want to send as a JSon the results of a query in PHP to my application.

Basically, my result contains multiple results with each one having the same and following attributes

- id
- date
- owner
- extension
- filename

I want to put them inside an array in such a way that each item's result is an array itself inside the bigger array just like the below image.

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: share your data sample and your code ?

Comment: So nested arrays?

Comment: create the multidimensional array and then just encode it to json?

Comment: $a=array();
$b=array("id"=>1,"date"=>2016-01-01","owner"=>"john"......);
$c=array("id=>2,-----);
$a[]=$b;
$a[]=$c;

Comment: You're looking for multidimensional arrays, you should did a search on that and you'll find better examples than it can be given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your query you can build an array the way you want (these are called multidimensional arrays) by using

```
   $res = mysqli_query("SELECT `xx` FROM `xx`");
   $images = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      $images[] = $row;
   }
   return json_encode($images);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need this?

```
$arrayInArray = array(
array("Thing1","Thing2"),
array("Thing3","Thing4")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an image `$image` which is an array containing your attributes id, filename and so on.

Then just create array that hold all images and push it into that.

```
$images = [];
$images[] = $image; // Push image into images

// Or if you don't already have $image, you can also create and push at the same time
$images[] = [
    'id' => 1,
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate array like this

```
    <?php

        $data=[
          0=>[
                'id'=>1,
                'date'=>'3/3/2017',
                'owner'=>'ownerName',
                'extension'=>'yourExtension',
                'filename'=>'YourFileName'
            ],
              1=>[
                'id'=>2,
                'date'=>'3/3/2017',
                'owner'=>'ownerName',
                'extension'=>'yourExtension',
                'filename'=>'YourFileName'
            ]
        ]；

$jsonData=json_encode($data)//convert into jsondata to send     
     ?>
```

Then send this data.

Answer (score 1):

This is called multidimensional array , simple syntax for your requirement is

```
  Array(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1,
            [date] => 2021,
            [owner] => 'shebin',
            [extension] => 'png',
            [filename] => 'new'
        )
 )
```

In order to get the above structure you can simply use :
In this example ,
consider $images as multidimensional array so code will be like

```
        $images[0]['id'] = 1 ;
        $images[0]['date'] = 2021 ;
        $images[0]['owner'] = 'shebin' ;
        $images[0]['extension'] = 'png' ;
        $images[0]['filename'] = 'new' ;
```

Instead of 0 you can use variable so you can create multiple set of this array

```
$images[$i]['id'] = 1 ;
```